# QStandardPaths: which StandardLocation is best for log data

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a cross platform application written in Qt.
I used QStandardPaths::locate() to figure out where to write various config/data items of the app. The application is run by an individual user (aka. it is not a system service).

I wonder which StandardLocation is best suited for logs written by the application?